# Best practise to use file content as redis key?

Tags: redis, md5, hashcode

I have a function to do some calculation on a file, and want to put the result to cache.

The key problem is how to put the file content(in my situation, files with different path is quite possible to be the same file, so I have to use file content as key) to redis as key.

What I want is:

1. If I get two same files,  with different names or same names, I can get this "key" the same
2. For files with different content, the "key" is different.
   And, I want the size of the key is much smaller than the file itself.

I considered to use hashcode or md5 of file as key, but worried about the probability of hashcode/md5 conflict.

So I wonder if there are some other better solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are really trying to do - or maybe avoid doing. An example might help. In the mean time, maybe you could use the inode number of the file if you want to avoid the same file being called by different names. Try `touch fred; ls -i fred; ls -i "$(pwd)/fred"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, it's not the question.  I added some info.

Comment: Have you considered SHA-1 instead of MD5? Which Redis client are you using - Python?